# javascript to click a link every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click

I need a javascript routine that will click a link every n seconds until interrupted.  I did find a routine that clicked a button but I don't know how to point the function to a link rather than a .button.

Thanks,
Wayne

Comment: do you need to load a page every 5, or just hit a url every 5? if you need to load, then you have to use an iframe or greasemonkey. if the page you need to reload is itself, a meta refresh will work. if you just need to hit a url, then ajax or a `new Image().src=url` ping should cover you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're actually trying to click a link that doesn't navigate to another page (what you asked, I suppose), you would probably use jQuery:

```
var variableToCancelInterval = setInterval(function(){
  $("a.linkclass").click();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This will work only one time, he needs a functions that clicks the link n times until stopped by the user.

Comment: Felipe - assuming it doesn't redirect, it will click it every 5 seconds.

Comment: Great!  this is what I need to do.  Can you tell me how I tag the link <a href=""  /a> so that "a.linkclass" is clicked?

Comment: Is there someone that can help me implement the jquery function above.  I added the jquery library to my page and have tried various implementations without success.  t

Comment: Wayne: 5000 is in milliseconds, while "a.linkclass" corresponds to any <a class="linkclass">blah blah</a>.  You would use variableToCancelInterval only if you wanted it to stop, via clearInterval(variableToCancelInterval);

Comment: djvs - do I need to create the class in my CSS file or is it sufficient to have the class referenced in the javascript?  if I need to place is in the CSS... what would that statement look like?

Comment: Those are CSS  selectors, also used in jQuery - they do not require an entry in the CSS file, but only a corresponding node in the DOM (else it will return something like an empty array).

Comment: djvs- can't seem to make it work.  I've implemented the jquery library and wrapped your suggested code in a document-ready-function block.  then created my link <a class='linkclass' href=''>click this link</a> but no click activity when I refresh :(

Comment: Can't help you without knowing what error you get, Wayne.

Comment: Sure, low to no price, I'll send you an email.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger anchor as a click so you can use simulate function, jQuery team create this function which will support in in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE10.

so first you have to download this script for using simulate function after jQuery script. Here is a link and example:

```
$('a').simulate('click');
```

[jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js)